# do comments slow PHP down?

Tags: php

PHP is a interpreted language, and that would (normally) mean that comments have to be parsed and therefore cause a performance penalty.

However, as far as I know, PHP comes with an optimizer which compiles/converts the raw source code into some bytecode or similar, which would mean that comments get stripped out and therefore no longer affect performance at all.

Do comments affect PHP performance (no matter how tiny the impact may be) or not at all?

Comment: The performance hit would likely be sub-microsecond in time. At the very least it has to parse them out when doing it's initial bytecode pass. You could use a optimizer that stores the bytecode output which would be without comments.

Comment: you know you can test this yourself? just for fun remove all whitespaces as well and then place all code in a single file. But there's not much benefit

Comment: It's really hard to get a serious answer to theoretical questions.... @Jonathan: I said "no matter how tiny" for exactly that reason.

Comment: @David: No, can't test that if the impact is tiny. But somebody must be out there who understands PHP enough to be able to give the answer - or so I hope...

Comment: you have the answer from @JonathanKuhn , its marginal, very marginal (try xdebug) and also dependant on the server hardware, it's not something that is constant either. To say that the processes leading to opcode execution (scanning, parsing in this case of comments and whitespace) has zero effect is not true, but if you are using a accelerator, it is true when delivering cached opcode.

Comment: No, Jonathan said it is marginal while AMACB (first answer) said that the compiler (would that not be the optimizer?) removes that, so the whole situation is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, any comments for any server-side script are removed when compiled. It might take an extra .0001 milliseconds for their computer to remove that, but otherwise it doesn't do anything.